# Which type of Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

For programming the Android, which Eclipse do I need ? (I means Eclipse for c++ or java or ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse for Java Edition would be approriate http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation says, ["A Java or RCP version of Eclipse is recommended."](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#preparing)

Answer (score 0):

What really matters is that the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) plugin works on Eclipse **3.5** at this point, 3.6 has issues. Beyond that, you can essentially install it on any of the versions of Eclipse.

Why? Because the plugin manager can download plugins and dependencies, and the difference between editions is what plugins they're shipped with...